# Need help with wiring diagram for 14-3 for a switch,14-2 for power source, and light all connected in s junction box, thanks

Tags: electrical, wiring

Just need the correct wiring diagram to connect both 14-2 and 14-3 in a junction box

Comment: Is the light attached to this junction box, or...?

Comment: How about giving us a description of what you're trying to do and include a couple of pictures of what you've got. Your description... leaves a bit lacking.